# Repository Metadata and local packages

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I need help with *dnf*. I frequently need to install a fresh image of *fedora* server on a VM. Once that's done, every time I try to use *dnf* to search or install packages for the first time, it seems to go through updating its *metadata*, which takes a long time. Is there a way to fetch this data and store it locally and then, after the fresh install, may be I can update *dnf* locally?

Also say I need to install the same package over and over again on new images. How can I download the package locally and then move the files to the new image and use dnf to install from a local file, i.e. something like downloading a windows offline installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do this, and one more complicated one.

The more-complicated one would be some smart caching-mirroring system for DNF, which knows about package updates. You could use `keepcache=true` in the DNF config file, and then re-export those files in some way. But, that's kind of fiddly. Instead, I'd suggest one of the easier ones:

1. Set up a local mirror. Run rsync periodically (instructions [on the Fedora mirroring website](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#Mirroring)), and point your hosts at that. This is fairly easy, but will probably involve mirroring a lot of stuff you don't really need.
2. Set up a standard caching proxy server, and use that. You could just set up a regular server, or if you want to be more clever, do what's suggested in the blog post [Lazy distro mirrors with Squid](https://ma.ttwagner.com/lazy-distro-mirrors-with-squid/) — set up an "accelerating" server running on port 80, and pretend that it's your remote repository location.

Comment: hello, I think I like your number 1 easy way and I will try it. Can you clarify what you mean by saying mirroring a lot of stuff?      Also any tips on my second question?  Thank you.

Comment: I mean that you may use, say, 1000 packages, and there are 17000 packages in the repository, so, you'll be pulling down a lot of data you don't necessarily use for anything. If you've got the bandwidth and disk space, that's not a problem.

Comment: Which second question? The local install thing? I mostly was assuming that having a local mirror or cache would make that less of a big deal, but if you want, you can just `dnf install localfilename.rpm`.

Comment: Great, the local install sounds like what I need. Now can I ask how do download the package in the first place in a file format? Also why do I have to wait a long time when I first use dnf to search for a package? can I download whatever it's doing (I'm assuming it's some kind of metadata update) and install that manually?  Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume that it's the initial metadata download, yes. If you're grabbing that from your local mirror, it'll be faster. To just download packages, you can use [`dnf download`](http://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/download.html).